# SLSQP solver scipy with linear subset constraints

Tags: constrained-optimization, scipy, least-squares, constraints

I have been trying to solve a least squares problem of the following form:

$$
\begin{equation}
\min_{\vec{x}} \frac{1}{2} \lVert f(\vec{x}) - f_{\text{target}} \rVert_{2}^2 + \alpha\Big( \frac{1-\rho}{2} \lVert \vec{x} - \vec{x}_{\text{orig}} \rVert_{2}^{2} + \rho \lVert \vec{x} - \vec{x}_{\text{orig}} \rVert_{1} \Big),
\end{equation}
$$

where $f$ is a continuous function $ f: \mathbb{R}^{N} \to \mathbb{R}^{K}$ and $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. The first term in the objective function above is hence minimizing the distance between the vector $f(\vec{x})$ and a given vector $f_{\text{target}}$. The next two terms are regularization terms ($\lvert \cdot \rvert_{1,2}$ are the $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ norms respectively) . $\vec{x}_{\text{orig}}$ is the starting vector.

I have been able to get a solution in a fairly quick time by using the `scipy.optimize` function with `SLSQP` solver. However, the addition of linear constraints seems to not work. The constraints are of the form

$$
\begin{align}
l_{1} &\leq \sum_{i \in I_{1}} x_{i} \leq u_{1} \\
l_{2} &\leq \sum_{i \in I_{2}} x_{i} \leq u_{2} \\
&\vdots \\
l_{n} &\leq \sum_{i \in I_{n}} x_{i} \leq u_{n} \\
\end{align}
$$

where $I_{m}$ are partitions of $\{1 \cdots n \}$. So the constraints are on the sums of the elements of the vector $\vec{x}$.

I have attempted to integrate these constraints within the function call `optimize` through the `constraints` list.

```
def fun_upper_constraint(x, indices, ub):
    return ub - np.sum(x[indices])

def fun_lower_constraint(x, indices, lb):
    return np.sum(x[indices]) - lb

def generate_constraint_dict(indices, ub, lb):
    return {"type": "ineq", "fun": fun_upper_constraint, "args": (indices, ub)}, {
        "type": "ineq",
        "fun": fun_lower_constraint,
        "args": (indices, lb),
    }
```

Adding constraints this way causes the optimizer to not find the optimum with the status message `Positive directional derivative for linesearch`. Hence, I wonder whether there is a way to encode these constraints in a way that is compatible with what the `SLSQP` solver expects.